# exporting csv with p:dataexporter

Tags: csv, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to export my datatable as csv file with Primefaces-Dataexporter but when i download the csv file then i have to Format the table manually with the',' separator. Is it possible to Export already separated data (each column) as with xls Export?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

Update:

I'm trying to remove "" and also replace the separator , with ;

Comment: I fail to underatand what you mean by _"i have to Format the table manually with the',' separator."_? It works for me, it is a csv. Opening this in Excel might not show what you want but that is an Excel problem. Blame Microsoft for this

Comment: Kukeltje thanks for your fast reaction. But when i open the csv with Notepad then everything is written in single line. It is possible to get the Export separated in columns?

Comment: The comma is the separator.... and maybe your newline is not detected. Try a real editor (vim, notpad++)

Comment: Yes the CSV data exporter works fine for me I use it in Production all over the place.  Look at the data in raw Notepad++ like @Kukeltje said the commas are the separators.

Comment: ok but is it possible to remove " " and  also replace the separator(,) with ; ?

Comment: PrimeFaces dataExeporter supports 'postProcessing'... Use that

Comment: but is it possible with type=csv? How can i customize the dataexporter ? I really need to replace the separator